# how to show Only relevant information in dbgrid delphi

Tags: delphi

information:
I have an order form.
[image: http://img695.imageshack.us/i/delhi.png/]

With "keuze" and "aantal" it wright a new line. The Orderline gets an OrderID.
But the user may only see the orderline from his OrderID.

How can i make it work that it only shows, for example the OrderID "47" ?

```
procedure TfmOrder.btInvoerenClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    dm.atOrder.open;
    dm.atOrder.Append;
    dm.atOrder ['OrderStatus']             := ('Aangemeld');
    dm.atOrder ['klantID']                 := fminloggen.userid;
    dm.atOrder ['OrderDatum']              := Kalender.date;
    dm.atOrder ['Opmerkingen']             := leOpmerkingen.text;
    dm.atOrder.post;
    cbkeuze.Visible  := true;
    dbRegel.Visible  := true;
    leAantal.visible := true;
    btOpslaan.Visible:= true;
end;
```

This is the code for making a new Order

```
procedure TfmOrder.btOpslaanClick(Sender: TObject);
var orderid:string;
  begin
    dm.atOrderregel.Open;
    dm.atDier.open;
    dm.atorderregel.Append;
    dm.atOrderregel ['AantalDieren'] := leAantal.text;
    dm.atOrderregel ['OrderID']      := dm.atOrder ['OrderID'];
    dm.atOrderregel ['Diernaam']     := cbKeuze.Text;
    dm.atOrderregel.Post;
    leaantal.clear;
    cbkeuze.ClearSelection;
  end;
```

And this for a new orderline

thanks in advance

I know got a different error using this code:

```
 begin
      dm.atorder.Open;
      dm.atorder.filter   := 'KlantID = '  + (fminloggen.userid);
      dm.atorder.filtered := true;
      while not dm.atorder.Eof do
      begin
         cbOrder.Items.Add (dm.atorder['OrderID']);
         dm.atOrder.Next;

      end;
      dm.atOrder.Close;
   end;
```

It gives an error: The arguments are from the wrong type, or doesn't have right reach or are in conflict with each other.

here is userid declared.

```
var Gevonden: boolean;
    userid : string;
begin
  dm.atInlog.open;
  Gevonden := false;
  while (not Gevonden) and (not dm.atInlog.eof) do
  begin
      if dm.atInlog['email'] = leUser.Text
    then
      begin
        Gevonden := true ;
        inlognaam := dm.atInlog['email'];
        userid    := dm.atInlog['KlantID'];
      end
    else
      dm.atInlog.Next
      end;
```

this is obviously in another form

Comment: It appears in the second part of your question the userid is a local variable which would not be visible to the other form. Please confirm that the fminLoggen.userid is in fact a string (that can be converted to an integer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Filter`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSet_Filter.html) property of the data set:

```
atOrderregel.Filter := 'OrderID = 47';
atOrderregel.Filtered := True;
```

Comment: 47 was an exapmle, I need to filter it with the OrderID created in order. also I did nog made the dbgrid with code but with the tool pallet

Comment: @Jasper - You can substitute any number instead of 47, `atOrderregel.Filter := 'OrderID = ' + IntToStr(SomeInteger);`

Comment: @Jasper - Also, the controls bound to the data is irrelevant, if you use `Filter` the *DataSet* will be filtered, whether a DBGrid is bound to it or not..

Comment: Ok well I fixed that error. 

**and you sir, are my hero :p**
I got it working. You can also use this to make an bill or something? you can use the filter function for that too?

Comment: @Jasper - Possibly, I think it would depend on the database design, but honestly I don't know anything about bills. :p    'Filter' does what answers from Simon and Satch does on the client side, it's like the sql 'where'. Also see "[Creating Filters](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/5datasetcreatingfilters_xml.html)" in the documentation.

Comment: @Sertac, the filter gives now an other error I used the same method. see updated Question

Comment: @Jasper - If the field type is string you have to put quotes around the value: `dm.atorder.filter := 'KlantID = ' + QuotedStr(fminloggen.userid);`

Comment: Thanks! I can't test it properly because I am going crazy, now i am getting some invalid argument error where i never had an error before.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the grid's *columns* property statically in the object inspector, showing only the fields you need. If the columns list is empty (default) it is filled with all available fields.

Just add as many columns as you need and link each column to the corresponding field. You can reorder the columns and set the widths and titles individually. There are still some more properties available which are worth to explore.

Comment: I need all the columns, but not all the records.

Comment: But you did happen to answer *my* question (which was unrelated).  And for that I am very grateful.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming your grid is bound to a datasource component. This datasource is then linked with a TDataset descendant. There are a couple of ways you could acheive the desired filtering of the dataset to display only orderid 47.

Firstly, you could set the Datasets SQL property to contain a (server side) SQL query such as:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
```

You would also need to create a parameter in the dataset to pass the (changing) value for the required OrderID. So add a new Parameter to the dataset (@OrderID), and then at runtime you can set this parameter value in code, something like:

```
DataSet.Parameters['@OrderID'].Value := ParameterValue;
```

Alternatively, you could also FILTER the dataset (client side) to just show the correct data:
Set your SQL property of the dataset to retrive the entire table, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

And then at runtime you could set the Filter property of the dataset to only get OrderID 47:

```
Dataset.Filter := 'OrderID = '+InttoStr(ParameterValue);
```

Depending on your needs one method may suit better (performance/memory) wise.

As Najem has commented, there is also a third method - using a Master-Detail dataset relationship. This method works using two datasets, one is the master of the other. When the master table record is changed, the detail dataset is then filtered using the value defined in the `Key` or `MasterFields` property of the M-D relatioship.

Comment: what about Master-detail relationships

Comment: I think this @parameter only works with SQL Server (and maybe access), I'm not sure about Firebird, Oracle, DB2 or other products.. but you don't mention this in your post.

Comment: @jachguate - Correct, this should work for SQL server, access, MySQL. Not sure about the other DB's. Principle is there though, basically you need to create a parameterized query.

Comment: @Sinom, IMHO it is better to write generic answers or to state specific constraints like this as part of your answer... remember your answer is accessible to the whole Internet audience.

Answer (score -2):

If you are connected to some datasource you could always create a SQL Query. Something like:

SELECT * FROM YourDBTable WHERE OrderID=47

Comment: The orderid is changing with a new order made. 
so sometimes it is OrderID 47, but later it is OrderID 48 or 49

Comment: `SELECT *
 FROM Orderregel 
WHERE dm.atOrder ['OrderID']`
This doesnt work. How do i link it to a database value?

Comment: Have you got any field in the data that's unique? If you have, just change the query to search for that field instead. If you haven't got a unique field, I would advise you create one.

Comment: In my database "Order" OrderID is unique
in "Orderline" OrderID is refered to that unique key.